# MicrosoftDefenderForCloud- JIT inbound security rule preventing bastion connection to VM in Azure

Tags: azure

The inbound security rule named MicrosoftDefenderForCloud-JITRule recurringly added to our NSG, preventing bastion connection to virtual machine to AD users in our Resource group. This is recurring, automatically added even after multiple deletes of this inbound rule in our NSG. Why this occurs? How to handle the situation?

Answer (score 0):

> This is recurring, automatically added even after multiple deletes of this inbound rule in our NSG. Why this occurs? How to handle the situation?

If you have configured `JIT VM access` on a `VM`, an `NSG` rule with port `3389` will be automatically added to the `NSG`. Because of this, you are unable to access the bastion service, which requires port `443` access.

[image]

You can modify the settings to allow port `443` in the `JIT` configuration, enabling access to the bastion service.

[image]

Turn off `JIT VM` access if it is not needed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Venkat for the response. I could resolve with above settings in Azure